# Skobbler skmaps not showing when device is connected to 3G/4G

Tags: skmaps

I have two questions:

For loading skmaps, it takes a lot of data? because when im connecting on 3G/4G not on Wifi, map is not showing. On the other side, maps on Google Map/Waze/Apple are loading.

1- What's the difference? i have to configure some settings? 
2- How can i show map without loading map in OfflineMode?

Thanks for reply

Comment: See the SKMapsService class - inside check: connectivityMode http://developer.skobbler.com/docs/ios/2.4.0/Classes/SKMapsService.html#//api/name/connectivityMode